# getting input from child of child component in angular

Tags: angular, input, components

need some clarification on detecting the changes in a child of the child component
for example,
I have a parent component that contains a button to submit
and inside the parent component, I have a child-1 component
inside the child-1 component, I have the child-2 component containing forms
once the button is clicked from the parent component I need to get the form value from the child-2 component to the parent component
whenever the input changed

any solution?

[image]

Comment: share the code you tried till now if possible a stackblitz

Comment: No i did'nt try i have this question in my mind
Assume
Parent component contains submit button
in the parent we have child component contains some wrapper component
inside the wrapper component we have form

if i click the submit button i need to get the form data

Comment: place the form in a service and access the value anywhere, that's it

Comment: so if i have some fields which is not filled how i can show this field is mandated under the field as a error message on button click

Comment: you need to add the validation in the child/parent component using the formobject(will contain the errors) in the service, you are asking too broad a question, shrink it down to a well constructed question with working examples and simple output you need, then it will easy for the people here to assist you

Comment: @NarenMurali Mentioned what exactly needed for my case in the diagram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247530/discussion-between-bhu-and-naren-murali).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Input` & `@Output` decorators to pass in data to your child components. Check this StackBlitz out for a quick demo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f23te8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional examples right in the answers text. Then users won't need to visit another site to see examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different approach, where we move the variable needed to submit the form inside a service and then calling the submit method from the root comment.

child ts

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormService } from '../../form.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-child',
  templateUrl: './my-form-child.component.html',
})
export class MyFormChildComponent {
  myFormFather: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private formService: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.formService.form = this.form;
  }

  createForm() {
    this.myFormFather = this.fb.group({
      nickName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      age: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    alert('submitted');
  }
}
```

child html

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormFather" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm">
  Nickname: <input formControlName="nickName" /><br />
  Name: <input formControlName="name" /><br />
  Age: <input formControlName="age" />
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="myFormFather.invalid">Save</button>
</form>

<div>
  {{ myFormFather.value | json }}
</div>
```

parent ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormService } from './form.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}

  get form(): NgForm {
    return this.formService.form;
  }
}
```

parent html

```
<button (click)="form && form.ngSubmit && form.ngSubmit.emit()" type="submit">
  external submit
</button>

<my-form-father></my-form-father>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-with-child-component-zzyr76)